# Labelling multiple elements using loops

Tags: javascript, function, loops, input, label

I am currently trying to loop through multiple input boxes using loops but I don't know how to go about doing it.

My JS code:

```js
function tagger() {
  var t;
  for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pl")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")
  }
};
return tagger();
```

HTML:

```
 <h1 class="pizza">Pineapple</h1>
  <body class="maco">
    <div class="keys">
      <span class="press"  onclick="car()"><i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i><h2>Log In</h2></span>
      <span class="type" id="heyu"><input class="entry" placeholder="Password"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help rendered!

Comment: Please post relevant HTML code also.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add the t variable as index of (getElementsByTagName)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pl")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[t];
```

or you can use forEach Method is the best way for looping trough arrays

```
function tragger  () {
  var _Element = Array.from(document.querySelector("pl input"));
  _Element.forEach(function (ele) {
     //do some code for each input
     ele.value = 'etc';
  });
  }
tragger();
```